# Moving content from HashMap A to HashMap B using the data from A's Value to be a new Key

Tags: java, hashmap

Is it possible to populate a Hashmap with the KV - pairs of another Hashmap using the data within the source-map. For example, let's consider we have a map that looks like this:

```
Map<Position,Place> positionMap = new HashMap<Position,Place>();
```

Now consider the Place class contains both a String `category` and a `Position`object.

Is it possible to transfer the place objects from the positionMap into the categoryMap using a loop and using the `category` String found within the Place-object to act as the key of the new HashMap whose values will be sets of Places? So one set containing all places of category A and one containing the places of category B.

```
Map<String,Set<Place>> categoryMap = new HashMap<String,Set<Place>>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `groupingBy` operation:

```
Map<String,Set<Place>> categoryMap = positionMap().values().stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Place::getCategory, Collectors.toSet()));
```

However, you want to collect to `Set<Place>` so you have to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` for your `Place` class.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot